# Pass one line of recordset to a function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

While I am moving through a recordset, I want to pass the current line through to another function. How could I do that?

I have set rs = "my_query".  As I loop through rs, starting with the first record and moving through until the last record, I pass the current record to another function that fills out a table with all of the fields in the query.  Right now I have to list every field I want passed into the other function and written to the table.  It seems like there should be an easier way to get the current record written to a table.  In the example below I am only showing 3 fields.  "my_query" actually has a lot of fields.  It is also a lot of work to change all of the references to the WritetoTable function when we add or remove fields from the query.

I'd like to just pass the whole rs to the WritetoTable function, but I don't know how to do that while making sure I only write the one record I want into the table.

```
Set rs = "my_query"
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Call WritetoTable(rs!field1, rs!field2, rs!field3......)
rs.MoveNext
Loop

Function WritetoTable(field1 as string, field2 as string, field3 as string...)
Dim rsTable as DAO.Recordset

Set rsTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Table,dbOpenDynaset)

With rsTable
.AddNew
!Field1 = field1
!Field2 = field2
!Field3 = field3
.update
End With

rsTable.Close
Set rsTable = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Why are you not using an Append query?

Comment: Does the function do something that can't be done another way? For each row of records, what is it that you must do in the function that you cannot do using SQL/MS Access functions?

Comment: I haven't used an append query in VBA before.  How would it be different or more simple than writing the record to the table using code like I have?  I reference the WritetoTable function in several other places in my code.  I put it in a separate function to make it easier to make changes.

Comment: An append query would be much simpler and much faster. However, you have to ask yourself, do I really need the same data in two tables?

Comment: Just curious why you feel the need to use VBA?

Comment: I was using VBA because this is part of a bigger set of code.  Depending on the information in the individual record, the results may or may not need to be written to the table at this point in the process.  I may be able to use an append query in my WritetoTable function, but I'm still not sure how to append only the one record I am currently looking at.

Comment: @OverMind There is a lot to be said for running queries in VBA. For one, it allows the coder to set up a sequence of events.

Comment: Nigel, use a unique ID to get the record you wish to append.

Comment: @Remou while I agree, there is nothing in this post that indicates such use.

Comment: Thank you for the unique ID idea.  Is there something that stores the record I am currently looking at?  The position of the record?  I may be able to add a unique ID into the query, but it would be easier if I could just store the line I am looking at as a variable.

Comment: @Nigel we need sample data to accurately answer your question. Do you know SQL? You can use the `WHERE` clause to filter which records you want to append.

Comment: I was able to use rs.AbsolutePosition to figure out which record I was looking at and write it to the table.  I realize a unique ID would be a better solution, but the query I have doesn't create a unique ID right now.  Thank you for heading me in the right direction.  I appreciate both of your questions.  It helps me see my code from a different perspective.

Comment: Please remember that absolute position is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Why would it have a problem in my example above?  The query has already run and been stored as a recordset.  I am steping through the recordset line by line.  I want to pass the specific line I am currently examining into my WritetoTable function.  Is there a reason that would not work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Remou and Overmind for leading me in the right direction.  I decided to use the bookmark property of the recordset to ensure I could come back to the same place.  The code below looks at each line in the query result and passes it to the WritetoTable function.

It is true that I could simplify this to an append query if it was as simple as the code I have shown.  In my situation it would take a lot of time to run such specific queries off a big server table.  So I run one query that has data in it that needs to be sorted out into various tables.  The query still takes a long time but at least it only has to run once.  I then have to go through the query results one line at a time to see which table it should be written to.

The code below lets me look at each line of the query result.  When it needs to be written to my table I can pass the whole recordset into the WritetoTable function and use the bookmark to write only the one line I was looking at.  I don't know if the code runs slower or faster than what I had before, but it is easier to edit and make changes to.

```
Set rs = "my_query"
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    vPosition = rs.Bookmark
    Call WritetoTable(rs, vPosition)
rs.MoveNext
Loop

Function WritetoTable(rs as Recordset, vPosition as Variant)
Dim rsTable as DAO.Recordset

Set rsTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Table,dbOpenDynaset)
rs.Bookmark = vPosition

With rsTable
.AddNew
!Field1 = rs!field1
!Field2 = rs!field2
!Field3 = rs!field3
.update
End With

rsTable.Close
Set rsTable = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

An append query would be much simpler and much faster. However, you have to ask yourself, do I really need the same data in two tables?

```
 Dim db As Database
 Set db = CurrentDB

 sSQL = "INSERT INTO ATable (Field1, Field2) " _
      & "SELECT FieldA, FieldB FROM BTable " _
      & "WHERE BTable FieldX='Y'"

 db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

You could also have a saved query and simply run it in VBA. For Example:

```
 db.Execute "AQuery", dbFailOnError
```

Note that db.Execute will only work with action queries.

It is often best to use an instance of CurrentDb, because it will allow you to get RecordsAffected.

You can also append from an external database, for example:

```
 INSERT INTO ATable SELECT * FROM [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=Server;DATABASE=Database;uid=User;pwd=Password].AnotherTable t WHERE t.FieldX Like "w*"
```

You need to ensure you have a good connection string. It is generally best to list the fields / columns, rather than trying a wildcard.

Comment: I don't have two tables.  I have a query where I need to examine each line to see if it should be written to a table at this point in the process.  As I go line by line through that query I would like to write only the line I am currently examining into the table.  I see where I could combine this into one append querry if I didn't have to sort out the results, but in this case it is easier to have one large query run one time and then sort the results and perform different actions based on the results.

Comment: Are you writing a line to the same table as you are querying? I think you need to post sample data and clarify your question. If you want to go on in your current direction, pass the unique id to your function and use that to open a recordset. It is very inefficient.

Comment: "my_quey" pulls data from a server side table.  I'm writing the results into one of my own Access tables.  The query results don't have a unique ID right now, though I may be able to build one into the query.  Is there a way to see the current position I am looking at while going through a recordset?

Comment: No, there is not. You need an Id. It is quite possible to run a complex query from MS Access that refers to an external database.